# Using perl's Regexp::Grammars, how do I make a capture dependent on $MATCH?

Tags: perl, regexp-grammars

I've got a token like such:

```
<delim2=((?{ $MATCH{delim} }))>
```

and what I want to happen is for `delim2` to capture and be set to the value of `delim`. When I run this, `delim2` is set, but the capture is never done. I think this is an error in my reasoning: I'm trying to chain this form:

```
<ALIAS= ( PATTERN )>     Match pattern, save match in $MATCH{ALIAS}
```

and this form: `(?{ MATCH{delim} })` into something like this

```
<ALIAS= ( (?{MATCH{delim}) )>     Matches the value of $MATCH{delim} save to $MATCH{delim2}
```

but this simply doesn't seem valid.  I can verify my original token works `<delim2=((?{ die $MATCH{delim} }))>` will die with the value, and, if I hard code it, I get the right capture and everything works `<delim2=(')>`? So how do I go about achieving sane results, while having a dynamic pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?{ $MATCH{delim} })` doesn't assert that `$MATCH{delim}` appears here in the input; only that it's a true value. Regexp::Grammars should have a "named-backreference" construct like perl `\k<NAME>` but it doesn't (and you can't use `\k<NAME>` because Regexp::Grammars stores its results somewhere entirely different).

You could do something like

```
(??{ quotemeta $MATCH{delim} })<delim2=(?{ $MATCH{delim} })>
```

which is horrible but seems to work in testing. Or you could give in and go to Parse::RecDescent which has better support for this kind of thing. Or you could start hacking on R::G.

Comment: I would upvote this one twice if I could. I actually had the answer from D yesterday, but your addition of `quotemeta` just solved a problem I've been working on for a while. Thanks -- In fact, I'll take it one step further, I hereby take everything negative I've said about you in the past month back. hobbs++

Comment: Damian says, «In the next release of Regexp::Grammars, you're going to be able to use what I'm calling "subrule backreferences".»

Comment: I haven't even heard from you in the past month. Shit, that means you're talking behind my back ;) Anyway, I'm glad to hear that Damian is working on it.